# MySQL searching for a keyword

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I need to find all the plubisher names that contain the word AND.  The teacher showed us his output file and it shows the following results:

```
#12.
+--------------------------+
| PublisherName            |
+--------------------------+
| Farrar Straus and Giroux |
| McPherson and Co.        |
| Simon and Schuster       |
| Thames and Hudson        |
+--------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My code that I used is:

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBLISHER
WHERE PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE '%AND%';
```

However, my results pulls in an extra publisher:
Random House
due to the and in random.

Can someone point me in the right direct on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding spaces between the text and the wildcard.

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBLISHER
WHERE PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE '% AND %';
```

Comment: Thanks!  The only thing I didn't try haha.